# SSAS Installation fails when trying to start services after repeated attempts

Tags: sql-server, installation, ssas

I am trying to install Sql Server Analysis Services 2019 on my WIN10PRO machine.  I am running the installer from the SSEI 19 Dev installer package and regardless of me resetting my machine and starting completely over, I continue to be unable to run SSAS.  When I check the msmdsrv.log file, I see these messages (amongst others):

```
(6/30/2022 9:13:36 PM) Message: The service cannot be started: The following error occurred during a file operation:  Access is denied. . (\\?\C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS15.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Data). (Source: \\?\C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS15.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Log\msmdsrv.log, Type: 3, Category: 289, Event ID: 0xC1210000)  

(6/30/2022 9:13:36 PM) Message: Service stopped. (Source: \\?\C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS15.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Log\msmdsrv.log, Type: 1, Category: 289, Event ID: 0x41210001)
```

I am the administrator of this machine and ran the executable as admin so I'm not sure why I'm receiving this error.

I have ensured that this path:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS15.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Data
```

exists.  There is a cleanup directory present and nothing else.

Comment: Have you checked what account the SSAS service is configured to execute with (via Services or service.msc)? Does that account have at least Modify, probably Full Control, permissions in the ACLs of the `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS15.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Data` folder?